# Image Magick ERROR_MODULE UnableToLoadModule

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

I'm randomly getting this error while running ImageMagick with Go `` ERROR_MODULE (0): UnableToLoadModule `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.10/modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1314 ``

`Go` Code

```
imagick.Initialize()
_, err = imagick.ConvertImageCommand(cmd)
 #error handling
imagick.Terminate()
```

Where `cmd` is

```
convert  /tmp/sampleImg.jpg  -resize  160x120>  -transparent  white  -gravity  center  -extent  160x120  -quality  82  -interlace  line  -background  white  -dither  none  -define  jpeg:fancy-upsampling=off  -define  png:compression-filter=5  -define  png:compression-level=9  -define  png:compression-strategy=1  -define  png:exclude-chunk=all  /tmp/160x120/sampleImg.jpg
```

Comment: Please define "randomly": does this reliably happens when you run _the same_ command (I mean, literally the same) multiple times in a row? Or does it only happen on JPEG files, which I'd guess it really does? Another question: does this happen when you run the `convert ...` command by hand (in a shell console window)?

Comment: Also, judging from [this search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=jpeg.la&mode=&suite=focal&arch=amd64), are you sure you have the `libmagickcore-6.q16-6` package installed on the machine you run this command on? If yes, does doing `apt install --reinstall libmagickcore-6.q16-6` fix the problem?

Comment: Also, does `convert -list format | grep -i JPEG` return anything?

Comment: That happens once in a 100 or maybe 500 times. When I try to load files from database and resize them
I have a products with multiple images and each image needs to be resized to multiple sizes
Also, this file does exists `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.10/modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.la` not sure why sometimes for the same image file ImageMagick fails to load it

Comment: @kostix

`JNG* PNG  rw-   JPEG Network Graphics`

JPE* JPEG  rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.3)

`JPEG* JPEG  rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.3)`

JPG* JPEG  rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.3)

`JPS* JPEG  rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.3)`

PGX* PGX   rw-   JPEG 2000 uncompressed format

`PJPEG* JPEG  rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.3)`

Comment: reinstalling `libmagickcore-6.q16-6` doesn't fix it as well

Comment: «That happens once in a 100 or maybe 500 times» — can you try two experiments? Have a "known good" file—a file on which this error did not happen,—and try to run that conversion command on it any huge number of times (like, I dunno, 10000 times)? Another one is to take a "known bad" file—one on which the command failed,—and try to run that same command on it multiple times—does it reliably fail on such file? I mean, if there will be no statistical difference in the outcome of running the conversion command on both kinds of file, the problem is definitely in the environment.

Comment: But as you can see, the Q&A format offered by SO is clearly not suitable for this sort of problem which requires multiple backs and forths. So, can we restart on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) instead? Or maybe on [`r/golang`](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/).

Comment: Issue fixed by updating to ImageMagick 7